# adding new key inside a new key and assigning value in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

`dic = {'Test': {'cities':5}}`

it is easy to add a key-value pair inside

`dic['test']`

by simply writing

`dic['Test']['random'] = 1`

which gives output like this.

`{'Test' : {'cities':5, 'random':1}}`

but what if I want to add a key:key- value. i.e from above step I want a output like:

`{'Test' : {'cities':5, 'random':1, 'class':{ section : 5}}}`

This doesn't works which I thought may work. `dic['Test']['class']['section'] = 5`

it gives a key error 'class' .

For my specific case I am assigning data frame's row as key in iteration somthing like this.
`dic[df.iloc[i]['column1']][df.iloc[i]['column2']] = df.iloc[i]['column3']`

where column1 itself is not in the key.
How to do it, I am using python 2.7

Comment: the "value" you want to add is a dictionnary there, not `5` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...

```
dic['Test']['class'] = {'section': 5}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two options, in one line:

```
dic['Test']['class'] = {'section': 5}
```

in two lines:

```
dic['Test']['class'] = {}
dic['Test']['class']['section'] = 5
```

Comment: already the answer ... what is the interest to add yours which is exactly similar?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I don't see your answer !

Comment: well it is not exactly the same since I'm proposing an alternative !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `update` also.

```
dic['Test'].update({'class':{'section': 5}})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> dic
{'Test': {'cities': 5}}
>>> dic['Test']
{'cities': 5}
>>> dic['Test']['random'] = 1
>>> dic
{'Test': {'random': 1, 'cities': 5}}
>>> dic['Test']['class'] = {'section':5}
>>> dic
{'Test': {'random': 1, 'cities': 5, 'class': {'section': 5}}}
>>>
```